# AngularJs How to take out the function code from controllers to services

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-services

I want that my controller have more cleared code. And i want to take out some regular functions to services. Can anyone help me, how i can call function in services from html ???

```js
$rootScope.del_index = function (array, resp) {
  var array = array;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    if (array[i].id == resp){
                      array.splice(i, 1);
                    } else continue;
    } 
    return array;
}
```

```html
<p ng-click="$root.del_index(array, resp)"></p>
```

Comment: There is no direct way. You can reference to that service method in your controller. Say $scope.del_index = myService.del_index; Now you can call it from HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. That is the idea of controllers, to stand between services and the view, helping each of them by providing what they need to do their job. This way your the services are just doing business logic and raw data, while the view is just displaying perfectly view-friendly formatted data.

However, you can obviously have a controller function that does nothing else than call a service function.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But AngularJs Best practices told: "Keep the functions with same functionality in services". But if do this tips, i will get duplicate functions (1 - in service, 2 - in controller, cause i should call service function when ng-click event will happens) right?

Comment: @trigger the that is correct. The controller just "connects" the view to the service though, that is not duplicate functions. You dont copy-paste the code 10 times, you just write functions that call other functions, which is perfectly fine.